# Get the generated Id from the last insert in the Controller, Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my controller that saves form data in the database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/newUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewSurvey(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    userService.saveUser(user);
    modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Added user!");
    modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
    modelAndView.setViewName("user/newUser");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

After calling saveUser, how do I get the generated ID for that user in this controller, so that I can use it to call another function ?
Thank you

Edit :

UserService implementation :

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Override
public void saveUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: Can you post you code in the userService and in the dao that you use to save the user?In addition, in your entity how do you generate the Id, what strategy do you use,  ie @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) ?

Comment: I added the service implementation. And Yes. @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is how I generate it

Answer (score 3):

try the following the let me know if it worked for you

```
@Override
public User saveUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

change also the interface method to return the User in the UserService Interface

```
public User saveUser(User user);
```

then in the controller just call the getId() from the returned UserObject

```
User newUser = userService.saveUser(user);
newUser.getId();
```

Comment: If you do not specify the user id in your user object, and this id column is an auto_increment field in your database, then your function will always return 0.